# Append to closest div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I insert data into `<div class="reply_form"></div>` so it doesn't append to each instance of the `"reply_form"` class ?

```
{% for comment in comments %}

    {{comment.name}} 
    <p>{{comment.text}}</p>
    <div class = "buttonDisplayForm" data-path={{path("new", {'blog_id' : BlogPost.id})}} data-id= {{comment.id}}>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Reply</button>
    </div>
    <div class="reply_form"></div>

{% endfor %}
```

I am currently doing this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".buttonDisplayForm").on('click', function() {
        var path = $(this).attr('data-path');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            url: path,
            success: function(data){
                $(".reply_form").empty().append(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I want to add form with this, the `empty()` prevents adding more forms by click the button multiple times, but this also adds form fields to every `reply_form` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to store the current object `$(this)` in variable so you could use it inside inside the success callback to refer to the related `reply_form` with the clicked `buttonDisplayForm` button :

```
$(".buttonDisplayForm").on('click', function() {
    var _this = $(this);
    ...

    success: function(data){
        $(".reply_form", _this).empty().append(data);
    }
```

**Full code :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".buttonDisplayForm").on('click', function() {
        var path = $(this).attr('data-path');
        var _this = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            url: path,
            success: function(data){
                $(".reply_form", _this).empty().append(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**NOTE :** We store the `$(this)` object out of the callback since it will be different inside it and refers to the `jqXHR` object of the Ajax call instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That works, thanks. Why doesn't $(this) works inside ajax success ? I wanted to use `$(this)` but I couldn't figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: Since inside the callback, `this` refers to the jqXHR object of the Ajax call, not the element the event handler was bound to. You're welcome, glad i could helps. Happy coding.

Comment: I edited the HTML in OP.  Problem was that if `<div class="reply_form"></div>` was inside the `buttonDisplayForm` div then it would trigger the JS when I click on text field of form, i want it to be triggered only after clicking on Reply button.  Now `reply_form` is not inside `this`, so I tried to use `closest(".reply_form")` but that doesn't work. Any ideas ? thanks

Comment: Try `.next(".reply_form")` instead. since the replay form now if just next of the button

Comment: I use it like this `$(_this).next(".reply_form").empty().append(data);` and it doesn't do anything.